# Migrating local changes back to master after a pull request has been merged

Tags: git

I find myself doing this pattern a lot while working on a branch:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git pull
git stash pop
```

which happens if I'm working on a pull request, I send it out, and I start working on a dependent change but don't want to put the dependent change in the same pull request. Meanwhile, the pull request gets reviewed and merged into master, thus I need to migrate my latest changes into master.

Is there a more effective way to do this? I find it to be a little bit tedious and possibly error-prone if I have made separate pushes to the pull request's branch because my local changes suddenly become the incoming changes in the git merge instead of the other way around. What I'm looking for is a git command that will merge the latest changes *from* master into my branch and then migrate back to into master.

Is this possible in a single command?

Comment: *I need to migrate my latest changes into master.* - I don't get of doing `git stash pop` while being in master branch. You migrate change to master only via PRs, nope? You can always make alias for a chain of commands if they are tedious.

Comment: `git config --global alias.pm-master '...your chain of commands'`